# Как делаются команды с опциями? Python Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, любой-язык, telebot

Подскажите, как сделать команду с опциями для бота в телеграм (pytelegrambotapi)? Вот например:

```
/sendalluser привет
```

вы не поняли.. мне нужно сделать команду с опциями, то есть кто то например пишет /check 8 и если у меня присутствует в заданном массиве эта цифра, то я обрабатываю эту опцию....

Answer (score 3):

Команды добавляются через [BotFather](https://t.me/botfather), а не программно:

<kbd>/mybots</kbd> > <kbd>@your_bot</kbd> > <kbd>Edit Bot</kbd> > <kbd>Edit Commands</kbd>

Добавляя команду своему боту, добавьте краткое и понятное описание для пользователя - оно будет отображаться в списке команд.

---

Использование команд с параметрами ничем не отличается от обычной обработки сообщений - программно обрабатывать такие сообщения нужно с учётом того, что у команды могут/не могут быть параметры.
В указанном случае, например, можно обрабатывать поступившее сообщение следующим образом (*псевдокод*):

```
if (message.text == sendalluser)
{
   var s = split(message.text, ' ');
   var option = "Пока";
   if (s.count > 1) 
   {
      option = s[1];
   }

   bot.send(chatId, option);
}
```

Comment: вы не поняли.. мне нужно сделать команду с опциями, то есть кто то например пишет /check 8 и если у меня присутствует в заданном массиве эта цифра, то я обрабатываю эту опцию....

Comment: и основываюсь именно на опции,чтобы не делать код громоздким вслучае большинства опций

Comment: Это вы не поняли. Перечитайте ответ. Других вариантов нет

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def check(message):
    print(message.text.split())

>>> ['/check', '1', '2', '3']

    print(message.text.split()[1])  # [0] будет выводить /check
    print(message.text.split()[2])
    print(message.text.split()[3])

>>> 1
    2
    3

    m = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
    if message.text.split()[1] in m:
       print('в массиве')
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте aiogram.

В этой библиотеке есть уникальный метод **set_my_commands**.

```
from aiogram import types
async def set_default_commands(dp):
    await dp.bot.set_my_commands([
        types.BotCommand('start', 'Запустить бота'),
    ])
```

С помощью метода BotCommand мы задаём необходимые команды

Answer (score -1):

BotFather пишешь */mybots* >> выбираешь бота >> edit >> edit comands

Answer (score -1):

Поздно, но все таки. Если для команды нужен только один аргумент можно сделать так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def decode(message):
    m = message.text
    n = int(m[7:])
    #дельнейшие действия
```

То-есть просто отсекайте команду. (7 потому что `len("/check ") == 7`)